# "Запрокинув голову глядя на луну". Правильна ли фраза?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, однородные-члены, деепричастный-оборот

*В какой-то момент я остановилась, тяжело дыша и **запрокинув голову глядя на** **луну**, которая зависла словно надо мной, а оборотень — он стоял сзади, не трогая меня, но так, что я всей спиной ощущала его присутствие.

[**Е. Звёздная. Шепот в темноте**](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=67332&p=50)*

Не могу понять, возможна ли такая конструкция? Деепричастие с зависимым словом + деепричастие с зависимым словом — "кто здесь главный"?
Это ошибка, или какая-то особенная форма соединения, или просто неправильно расставлены знаки? Поясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

В какой-то момент я остановилась, тяжело дыша и **запрокинув голову** (= с запрокинутой головой) глядя на луну, которая зависла словно надо мной...

Глядя (как?) запрокинув голову. Деепричастный оборот в функции наречного выражения (обстоятельство образа действия).

Грамматика и графика предложения не из лучших, хотя формальных ошибок с деепричастиями нет.

Вариант редактирования:    **В какой-то момент я остановилась и, тяжело дыша и запрокинув голову,  глядела на луну, которая словно зависла надо мной....**

Comment: Дело в том, что в примерах, найденных мною, везде есть обособление. 1. ...она ушла, запрокинув голову, глядя в фиолетовое ночное небо, улыбаясь воспоминаниям... 2. Яска молчала, запрокинув голову, глядя в закатное небо. 3. Исси сидел, запрокинув голову, глядя на горные скалы. 4. ... просто стоял, запрокинув голову, глядя в мутное небо... 5. Он лежал, запрокинув голову, глядя на тусклый огонек коптилки...

Comment: Нет сомнений, что сочетание может использоваться  и как обособленный оборот, и как необособленное обстоятельство. Например: Амброджо сидел запрокинув голову, и лица его не было видно.  Пашка встал у окна и слушал, запрокинув голову к ясно-синему небу. Он лежал, запрокинув голову, хрипло и коротко дыша. Необособленное обстоятельство обычно относят к позе: сидел, стоял, лежал.

Comment: Из Ваших примеров только №2 кажется  абсолютно нормальным. Конечно, оборот можно обособить, даже если он относится к положению тела, но бессоюзная связь "сидел, запрокинув голову, глядя...",  "стоял, запрокинув голову, глядя..." кажется  странной, хотя бы союз И  могли бы использовать. Но всё это вопросы скорее художественного стиля и вкуса.

Comment: Отбросим спорную часть. Остается: "...я остановилась, тяжело дыша и глядя на луну". Писатель пописывает, а читатель почитывает... Не стоит такое и обсуждать.

Comment: Да уж, оставим ваш вариант, тем более что глядеть на луну  с опущенной вниз головой вряд ли получится.